# Missing Expression in UPDATE

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

I'm required to write a couple of UPDATE queries to parse data from a .csv file, but i do not know how the table works, i don't even have direct access to the Database, i just got an INSERT query like this one :

```
insert into lr_umbrales_valores (umcod_id, uvfec_dt, uvval_nm)
values ((select umcod_id from lr_umbrales
where lrcod_nm = (
    select lrcod_id from lr_lineas_referencia
    where me_metrica_nm = ?
    and fecha_baja_dt is null) 
and umtip_tx='S'), sysdate, ?)
```

So i'm trying this :

```
UPDATE LR_UMBRALES_VALORES SET UVVAL_NM = ? 
WHERE (
    SELECT UMCOD_ID FROM LR_UMBRALES 
    WHERE LRCOD_NM = (
        SELECT LRCOD_ID FROM LR_LINEAS_REFERENCIA 
        WHERE ME_METRICA_NM = ? 
        AND FECHA_BAJA_DT IS NULL
    ) 
    AND UMTIP_TX = 'S') 
AND UVFEC_DT = TO_DATE(?, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')");
```

This gives me a 'Missing Expression' Error (ORA-00936)

This is the only Information about the tables i got :

[image: Table to Update]
This is the Table i need to Update (its `UVVAL_NM`)

[image: Table from whom i get some Data]
From this one, i get the `UMCOD_ID` when `LRCOD_NM` is the same as the `LRCOD_ID` from the next table.

[image: Table to check]
Get the `LRCOD_ID` when `ME_METRICA_NM` is the same as the '`?`' parameter

Any tip in how to approach this? Needless to say, i'm completely new with SQL so this may be a very obvious mistake but i cannot get it right.

Comment: Remove `");` from the end?

Comment: @jarlh It's a part of the Java prepareStatement, i forgot to delete it from the question, sorry if it was missleading.

Answer (score 2):

This part

```
WHERE (
SELECT UMCOD_ID FROM LR_UMBRALES 
WHERE LRCOD_NM = (
    SELECT LRCOD_ID FROM LR_LINEAS_REFERENCIA 
    WHERE ME_METRICA_NM = ? 
    AND FECHA_BAJA_DT IS NULL
) 
AND UMTIP_TX = 'S')
```

causes the error. Maybe you wanted something like

```
WHERE UMCOD_ID = (
    SELECT UMCOD_ID FROM LR_UMBRALES 
    WHERE LRCOD_NM = (
        SELECT LRCOD_ID FROM LR_LINEAS_REFERENCIA 
        WHERE ME_METRICA_NM = ? 
        AND FECHA_BAJA_DT IS NULL
    ) 
    AND UMTIP_TX = 'S')
```

Comment: Thank you,  that solved it! but, may i ask for a brief explanation on the error so i can avoid it next time? I remember using that syntax in other kind of queries and they worked fine.

Comment: The subquery results in a value, and you must do something with it - compare it with another value, our use an `exists` clause etc.

Comment: jarlh: It always depends on what you want to accomplish. In many cases, `=(subquery)` can be replaced with a join.